# Funciones con dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, herencia, casting

debo realizar un programa, el cual es un consultorio el cual tiene una lista de la clase Embarazadas, que es una clase base de donde se derivan EmbarazadasDiabeticas, EmbarazadasJovenes, EmbarazadasMas35 y EmbarazadasPArterialAlta. Debo de implementar en la clase Consultorio seis funciones:

- Cantidad de embarazadas que se consideran en riesgo.
- Obtener el listado de las embarazadas diabéticas.
- Del total de embarazadas en riesgo cuántas tienen más de 35 años.
- Dado el nombre de una embarazada de tensión arterial alta conocer el valor de tensión arterial
  mínima alcanzada.
- Obtener el número de historia clínica de la embarazada diabética con mayor PTG
- Imprimir el valor del chequeo extra realizado de todas las embarazadas del tipo diabética y de
  presión arterial alta.

Lo debo de realizar utilizando dynamic_cast, esto es lo que tengo:

```
//Imprimir cantidad de embarazadas en riesgo
void EmbarazadasRiesgo() {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    int i = 0;
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if ((*it)->riesgo() == true) {
            it++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Cantidad de embarazadas en riesgo es de: " << i << endl;

//Imprimir listado de embarazadas diabeticas
void PrintEmbarazadasDiabeticas() {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it) != 0) {
            cout<<"Nombre completo: "<<dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getNombre();
            cout<<" "<<dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getApellido()<<". ";
            cout<<" No. de Historia Clinica: "<<dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getNoHClinica()<<". ";
            cout << "PTG: " << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getPTG() << endl;
            it++;
        }
    }
}
//Imprimir de las embarazas en riesgo, la cantidad que son mayores a 35
void RiegoMas35() {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    int i = 0;
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasMas35*>(*it) != 0) {
            while (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasMas35*>(*it)->riesgo() == true) {
                it++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "De las embarazadas en riesgo, " << i << "son Embarazadas mayores de 35 anios." << endl;
}
//Dado el nombre de una embarazada con PAA, imprimir el valor minimo alcanzado
void EmbPAAValorMinimo(string pNombre) {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it) != 0) {
            if (pNombre == dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it)->getNombre()) {
                cout << "Valor minimo alcanzado por " << pNombre << ": " << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it)->valorMinimo() << endl;
                it++;
            }
        }
    }
}
//Obtener el numero de historia clinica de embarazada diabetica con mayor PTG
void EmbDiabMayorPTG() {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    float mayor=0;
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it) != 0) {
            if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getPTG() < mayor) {
                mayor = dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getPTG();
                it++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getPTG() == mayor) {
        dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getNoHClinica();
    }
}
//Imprimir el valor del chequeo extra realizado de todas las embarazadas del tipo diabetica y de presion arterial alta
void printChequeoExtra() {
    list<Embarazadas*>::iterator it = embarazadas.begin();
    while (it != embarazadas.end()) {
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it) != 0) {
            cout << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getNombre() << ' ' << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->getApellido() << "Valor de glucosa: " << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasDiabeticas*>(*it)->ExamenGlucosa() << "mg/dl" << endl;
        }
        if (dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it) != 0) {
            cout << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it)->getNombre() << ' ' << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it)->getApellido() << "Pulsaciones: " << dynamic_cast<EmbarazadasPArterialAlta*>(*it)->ExamenPulsaciones() << "bpm" << endl;
        }
        it++;
    }
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutarlas en el main, solo funcionan la primera, la segunda y la ultima. Las funciones para que se imprima el total de embarazadas en riesgo que son mayores a 35, el que me da el valor mínimo de tensión arterial dado un nombre y la que me da el numero de historia de la embarazada diabetica con mayor PTG no funcionan. ¿Podrían ayudarme? Es muy importante.
Gr

Comment: En una condición, no es necesario comparar el resultado de un dynamic_cast con 0(aunque si lo tienes que poner, deberías cambiar 0 por nullptr). Tampoco es necesario comparar el resultado de llamar ->riesgo() con true. Si regresa true entra, si no, no.
También el código sería mucho menos complicado si usaras for en lugar de while, por ejemplo:

void EmbarazadasRiesgo(){

    for(Embarazadas* embarazada: embarazadas){

        if(embarazada->riesgo()) ....